# I want to create a twitter username generator, that checks if random strings is vaild for twitter as username

Tags: json, node.js, twitter

So I want to use:

A:
http://www.sethcardoza.com/api/rest/tools/random_password_generator/complexity:alphaNumeric/type:json/length:2

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "password": "uy",
    "length": "2",
    "complexity": "alphaNumeric"
}
```

B:
https://twitter.com/users/username_available?username=uy

```
{
    "valid": false,
    "reason": "taken",
    "msg": "Username has already been taken",
    "desc": "That username has been taken. Please choose another."
}
```

Where I want the "password" string generated in A, inserted in the url in B, until a "valid" boolean in B is true. So basicly I want to create a twitter username generator, that checks if random strings is vaild for twitter as username, how do I do this?

Edit: I want to do this with node.js .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not written what language you want to write this program in. If you want to use PHP there is a function called [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) that converts an json-string to an array in PHP.

You can use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the URL and the data of the url.

Complete code to check url, and to convert it into an array in PHP is the following:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://twitter.com/users/username_available?username=uy"), true);
if($data["valid"]){
    echo "Valid Username";
}
else{
    echo "Invalid Username";
}
```

Note the "true" parameter set in the json_decode() function call. It is used to make the json an array.